# Providing end users with data integration capabilities on front end

Tags: reactjs, django, architecture, product

I am doing research as part of new product development and unable to find the right answer.

Would like to provide end users with data integration and load to back end capabilities. They will connect to different sources (excel, dbs, other applications) of financial data, select tables and features needed to be loaded to back end.

Instead of building from scratch, any tech out there that we could integrate direct to provide these features to end users.

Backend is Django and front end is react for current stack with Postgres as db.

Tried to search in Django and react documentation as well as google